# Value (not index) greater than 3 in array causes java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, exception

I'm a novice programmer. This may be a simple problem but I've never seen this before. First of all, let me clarify that I'm not even trying to manipulate the index. Here's the part of the code that is causing the exception:

```
    int[] bumpercatcher = new int[4];


//time variable that helps control events
int time = 0;

public void setup()
{
    bumpercatcher[0]=4;
    bumpercatcher[1]=4;
    bumpercatcher[2]=4;
    bumpercatcher[3]=4;
```

As you can see I'm trying to set them all equal to 4 at the start of the program. This causes the arrayindexoutofbounds exception. If I set them all equal to 0~3 then there is no problem (until I set them to a value greater than 3 later in the program). I don't understand it.

-it doesn't matter if I set the array size to 10, I still get the same exception

-it doesn't matter if I set only one of the values (i.e. at index 1, which is **definitely** within bounds of the array). same exception

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

well, here' the entire code if you want to take a look(not too long, 1 class, bad programming practies): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33501308/Pong.java

Here's the html from which you can see the program from (not much to see. it just freezes instantly.): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33501308/bin.zip

by the way I'm using eclipse.

I don't really know what SSCEE is. sorry

Comment: Please show the code where the Exception appeared.

Comment: It almost sounds like somewhere you are using an element's value as an index. Sort of like `int x = bumpercatcher[0]; int someOther = bumpercatcher[x];`. But your code as presented should have no problems, we'll need to see a bit more where the exception is actually happening.

Comment: It happens exactly when I set those variables, the program just freezes there. And this part is where I initialize everything.

Comment: Without seeing the actual stack trace, and some indication of where in the source the exception line is, we're all just guessing here.  Please update your post to include both pieces of information.

Comment: Show us a SSCEE. Simple, self contained, exectable example.

Comment: Well I didn't really know what you meant by SSCEE but I just included the code and those files

Comment: Should I just set 4 individual int variables instead of using an array? It would make me look bad though. Who am I kidding, I already look bad.

Comment: My psychic debugging might be accurate. In your file I see `for(int j: bumpercatcher) {  if(bumpercatcher[j]>5) ... }`, which is precisely what my original comment addresses. `j` is an element of the array. You are using it as an index. There are other loops just like that one.

Comment: WOW IT WORKS! I replaced those loops with for(int k=0; k<bumpercatcher.length;k++). Sorry about that. I assumed the above segment of code was the problem because when I commented it out or tried 0~3 it presented me with no errors. How very strange. I saw my professor doing that shortcut all the time. I guess I shouldn't try it. You should have posted it in the answers section. I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code file includes loops along the lines of

```
for(int j: bumpercatcher) { 
    if(bumpercatcher[j]>5) 
       ... 
}
```

This is an issue. This is a different kind of loop than a traditional for loop. It is an extended or enhanced for, also called a *foreach*. It reads "for each integer j in array bumpercatcher do x." You are taking your element j (a value) and using it as an index to the array. When your value exceeds the maximum index, you will get an exception.

Write your code with a proper for loop if you want to access by index, or try simply restructuring your logic like

```
for (int j : bumpercatcher) {
    if (j > 5) // j is the value!
        ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I would have never guessed this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but a far more readable way of doing this would be with a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bumpercatcher.length; i++) {
    bumpercatcher[i] = 4;
}
```